# Julia: How can I make this repeated conditional statement code shorter?

Tags: julia

I want to create 15 dummy variables and use them in the following code, which I like to make it shorter as well. So the question is that how can I make this 15 dummy variables without using `D1=zeros(3300)`, ..., `D15=zeros(3300)`.

Also, how can I make this more compact?

```
for i=1:3300
    if dt[i,2]==1 D1[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==2 D2[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==3 D3[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==4 D4[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==5 D5[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==6 D6[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==7 D7[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==8 D8[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==9 D9[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==10 D10[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==11 D11[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==12 D12[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==13 D13[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==14 D14[i]=1 end
    if dt[i,2]==15 D15[i]=1 end
end
```

Comment: How do you use the `D1`...`D15` variables later?  Is `dt` available later?  It seems curious that you would need `D1`...`D15`.

Comment: Experienced coders almost _never_ do this. In stead they use collections that they index into. Even though @BogumiłKamiński showed you how to do it, you should almost certainly use his _first_ suggestion, _not_ the second.

Comment: Fully agreed. I showed it only to answer the question (because this was the actual question) as what was requested is actually possible in Julia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend not to create variables `D1` to `D15` directly, but rather keep them in a vector of vectors and assign to them like this:

```
D = [zeros(3300) for i in 1:15]
for i in 1:3300
    D[dt[i,2]][i] = 1
end
```

Now `D[i]` is an equivalent of your `Di`.

And if you really want to have `Di` variables in global scope you can later write for example:

```
for i in 1:15
    eval(:($(Symbol("D", i)) = D[$i]))
end
```

and you will get `Di` variables.

---

---

The [`:`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Symbols-1) character has two syntactic purposes in Julia. The first form creates a Symbol, an interned string used as one building-block of expressions:

```
julia> :foo
:foo

julia> typeof(ans)
Symbol
```

The second is the Range operator. `a:b` constructs a range from a to b with a step size of 1 (a UnitRange) , and `a:s:b` is similar but uses a step size of s (a StepRange).

---

Julia allows interpolation into string literals using [`$`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation-1), as in Perl:

```
julia> "$greet, $whom.\n"
"Hello, world.\n"

julia> "1 + 2 = $(1 + 2)"
"1 + 2 = 3"
```

In a similar way you can interpolate into expressions e.g.:

```
julia> x = 1
1

julia> :(x = $x)
:(x = 1)
```

---

[`Symbol`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.MainInclude.eval) Creates a Symbol by concatenating the string representations of the arguments together.

```
julia> Symbol("my", "name")
:myname
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit suggestion. I have omitted it earlier, because, as it was discussed above - this is actually not recommended. Also I have added an explanation that interpolation works for strings and for expressions.